# Loading a surface using directx9 is too slow

Tags: c++, bitmap, directx, textures

Im trying to load a bitmap in order to render it on the screen,to do so im using loadSurfaceFromFile.
the images that i want to load are 1280*1024, it takes about 35ms to load these images.
it seems to me that it should load a lot faster(something like 5ms)
what im i doing wrong?

edited code:

```
QueryPerformanceCounter(&liStart2);
int size = load_file_to_memory(s.c_str(),&content);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&liStop2);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&liStart);
D3DXLoadSurfaceFromFileInMemory(surface,NULL,NULL,content,size,NULL,D3DX_DEFAULT,0,NULL);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&liStop);
LONGLONG llTimeDiff = liStop.QuadPart - liStart.QuadPart;
double dftDuration = (double) llTimeDiff * 1000.0 / (double) Frequency.QuadPart;
LONGLONG llTimeDiff2 = liStop2.QuadPart - liStart2.QuadPart;
double dftDuration2 = (double) llTimeDiff2 * 1000.0 / (double) Frequency.QuadPart;
```

Comment: 5ms seems too fast, the average seek time on a hard disk of that order of time. Then you are loading 4MB or so of data from your bmp file, which at a typical hard disk rate of 200MB/s will take 20ms or so. And that's before any processing is done on the data itsself...

Comment: 5ms is the time that i think it should take for loading from the memory to the surface and not from the hard disk.is there a better way the render an image from a file (maybe with something else then surface)?

Comment: Right, although your example loads from a file... Erm, preload everything you want into texture objects and draw them quickly when you need them?

Comment: Thats what im doing now(loading to a surface array),but since i have usually around 1000 images to load you need to wait a long time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to hide the load latency using multiple loader threads. [Here's](http://qstechiecorner.blogspot.com/2005/11/streaming-png-32-bit-argb-files-from.html) a discussion on the performance of loading textures from disk. I myself have utilized the last method outlined in the article there (by Jon Watte) with excellent results.

Hope this helps!

Comment: hiding the latency is a possible solution, but i still don't understand why does the surface/texture loading takes so long(20ms to load from memory to the device)

Comment: Have you profiled the code to see which part is the bottleneck? Is it the PNG decoding? The reading itself? The discussion I pointed to has many helpful hints on what to do depending on what is slow.

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't understand what you mean by "this is my update code". Could you clarify, please?

Comment: sorry,i edited the code,the bottleneck is in the D3DXLoadSurfaceFromFileInMemory call

Comment: Then, it seems to me that the bottleneck is decoding/decompression. Have you tried different file formats (I believe the supported formats are bmp, .dds, .dib, .hdr, .jpg, .pfm, .png, .ppm, and .tga) to see if that helps? Perhaps uncompressed PNGs?

Comment: isn't bmp an uncompressed format?, anyway i tried the others with no luck, they seem to work slower

Comment: Yes, the most common 24 bpp BMP is not compressed. In this case, it is possible that you might become read bottlenecked. If performance is critical for you, take a look at this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313251/fastest-png-decoder-for-net) other answer of mine related to GPU-based PNG decompression.

Comment: i decided to use multiple loaders and preload some of the data, its not ideal but nothing else seems to work.thanks anyway